# Why is it out of context?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have the following code in `C#`

```
if ((l = d.Length) > 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d[i]["id"]);
    }
}
```

and it puts a little red highlight under l and i and when I hover the mouse over it, it says

> The name i does not exist in the current context.

Why is that?

Comment: Where have you declared l, i and d? Show that code as well...

Comment: You can either declare `i` in somewhere out of the `for-loop` or in the ones written below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you haven't declared i properly it should be int i

```
if ((l = d.Length) > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d[i]["id"]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare `int i` in or before the `for` statement, otherwise how is it supposed to know what `i` is?

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(d[i]["id"]); 
}
```